# Python re expression - remove # followed by numbers up until a comma

Tags: python, substring, python-re

I have an string:

```
5956 Executive Dr #101, Fitchburg, WI 53719
```

I want it to be:

```
5956 Executive Dr, Fitchburg, WI 53719
```

I've tried:

```
string2 = re.sub("(\\.*)\\s+#.*", "\\1", string1)
```

But that just gets me:

```
5956 Executive Dr
```

How can I do this in Python?  I find re expressions so confusing.  Ideally I'd like to do the same thing with Apt, Unit, etc - replace any instance like "Apt 3", "Unit 3", "Suite 4" with "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is not the best here, you can use a simpler expression:

```
string2 = re.sub("\s#\d+", "", string1)
```

- \s - whitespace
- # - literal octothorpe
- \d+ - at least one digit

To also remove the other parts you can use `"(Apt|Unit|Suite)\s\d+"` or together `"\s#\d+|(Apt|Unit|Suite)\s\d+"`

Comment: Thanks Nullman!  Can you explain 1) octothorpe and 2) what exactly the /d+ is doing?  This worked for me.

Comment: you have something like `#101` in your text. an octothorpe is also known as a hashtag or pound, it's this `#` symbol. `\d` mean digit (0-9) the `+` means "at least one" so `\d+` will catch things like`32425234412342`